# How to compare (contents of) color objects retrieved from HTML5 canvas via ctx.getImageData()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'd like to compare (a limited number of) color values retrieved from an HTML5 canvas. So I retrieve and store what I'm interested in by `ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;`

I then tried to use the `Array.prototype.compare`  from: [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript) by:

```
// add the same compare method to Uint8ClampedArray
Uint8ClampedArray.prototype.compare=Array.prototype.compare;
```

That works fine on recent FireFox and Chrome but I soon found that not all browsers return an object of type Uint8ClampedArray. [IE seems to use an Object of CanvasPixelArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Safari seems to use a simple 4-value array](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PixelManipulation/PixelManipulation.html)

Do I have to deal with those differences myself or is there a reliable generelized method (plain JS or jQuery) to compare two such values retieved by ctx.getImageData() that works on all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (probably?) use the Array compare method like this:

```
var comparisonResult = [].compare.call(yourPixels, colors);
```

That code finds the "compare" method from an array instance and invokes it with your pixel array as the `this` value and the other array (your colors) as the first parameter.

This would be the same thing:

```
var comparisonResult = Array.prototype.compare.call(yourPixels, colors);
```

but it's more typing and I'm lazy. Anyway, as long as the pixels "look like" an array (they have a "length" property and `[]` indexing works) that should work for you.

*edit* — I just looked at the question you linked. If you just need a "compare" function for this purpose, there's no need to add it to the Array prototype, since you're not making use of it by that means anyway.  Just write a compare function that takes two arguments.